# Read Session Id using Javascript

Tags: javascript, session

Is it by any means possible to read the browser session id using javascript?

Comment: How did this question get these answers even though it didn't give any context. Really confused.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes. As the session ID is either transported over the URL (`document.location.href`) or via a cookie (`document.cookie`), you could check both for the presence of a session ID.

Comment: sarnath'd damn you :) Also worth mentioning some platforms write this out to a hidden field in a retrievable, determinable way.

Comment: That's great.  But how.  That's the question.

Answer (score 10):

The following can be used to retrieve JSESSIONID:

```
function getJSessionId(){
    var jsId = document.cookie.match(/JSESSIONID=[^;]+/);
    if(jsId != null) {
        if (jsId instanceof Array)
            jsId = jsId[0].substring(11);
        else
            jsId = jsId.substring(11);
    }
    return jsId;
}
```

Comment: Will that regex ever return anything but an Array with one value? There's no global modifier, so it should only return the first match or null if no match, which presumably is what you would want.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, a browser session doesn't have an id.

If you mean the server session, that is usually stored in a cookie. The cookie that ASP.NET stores, for example, is named "ASP.NET_SessionId".

Answer (score 6):

you can receive the session id by issuing the following regular expression on document.cookie:

```
alert(document.cookie.match(/PHPSESSID=[^;]+/));
```

in my example the cookie name to store session id is PHPSESSID (php server), just replace the PHPSESSID with the cookie name that holds the session id. (configurable by the web server)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short and sweet JavaScript function to fetch the session ID:

```
function session_id() {
    return /SESS\w*ID=([^;]+)/i.test(document.cookie) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}
```

Or if you prefer a variable, here's a simple one-liner:

```
var session_id = /SESS\w*ID=([^;]+)/i.test(document.cookie) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
```

Should match the session ID cookie for PHP, JSP, .NET, and I suppose various other server-side processors as well.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP's PHPSESSID variable, this function works:

```
function getPHPSessId() {
    var phpSessionId = document.cookie.match(/PHPSESSID=[A-Za-z0-9]+\;/i);

    if(phpSessionId == null) 
        return '';

    if(typeof(phpSessionId) == 'undefined')
        return '';

    if(phpSessionId.length <= 0)
        return '';

    phpSessionId = phpSessionId[0];

    var end = phpSessionId.lastIndexOf(';');
    if(end == -1) end = phpSessionId.length;

    return phpSessionId.substring(10, end);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can use `document.cookie` for that.

Answer (score -6):

you can probably ping the server via ajax inside javascript. The php file might look something like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = session_id();
echo $id;
?>
```

This will return you the current session id. Was this what you were looking for.

Comment: Javascript, not PHP