# Load mootools with require.js and passing server side php variables to java functions

Tags: javascript, php

I was trying to load mootools with require.js. It works fine but now I need to pass server side variable in PHP to this class initialization.

Here is the code where i want to pass sessionid from php variable, i need to pass many variables but in below example I have just mentioned one:

```js
require(['ext/mootools/mootools-1.2.6-core-nc.js',
    'ext/mootools/mootools_more.js'
  ], function () {
    require.ready(function () {
      ajaxCart = new AjaxShoppingCart({
        sessionId: "<?php echo $session_id;?>",
      });
    });
```

so my query is how can I pass those variable to require framework which I can use in difference java functions listed after require.ready.

Comment: You should probably read the session id from the client. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920670/read-session-id-using-javascript

Comment: Why did you title your question "Trying to load" when in the second sentence you say "it works fine" and ask about something completely different?

Comment: Should there not be a $ before your php variable? btw, how do you define it before echoing?

Comment: Thanks @kryger  I have tried to re-edit the question and content.

Comment: @Sergio thanks. I have modified. Actually I have lots of php variables which i need to pass to these functions at the time of initialization.

Comment: other option is to have "<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
" and than use create "require.config" and "require" in inline javascript block where I would have all php variables to play.